# New Google Maps query string syntax for a marker

Tags: google-maps, query-string

In my web page code, I used to have a link to open a new window with Google Maps initialized like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:{{lat}},{{long}}&z=14
```

and it was showing a marker.

With the new google maps, this syntax does not work completely, as the zoom level is not taken into account. So I found out that this was working:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/@{{lat}},{{long}},14z
```

But in this case I don't have a marker anymore.

Question: With the new syntax, how to get a marker at the specified position? Also, I could not find a Google web page documenting the syntax. Is there one?

Thank you

Comment: You have to use the [Static Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers). If you want an interactive map, you have to use the Google Maps Javascript API, here is a [demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) to show a marker in Google Maps using the Javascript API.

Comment: @ztan I'm not in a javascript context at all. I just want to generate a link that opens Google Maps centered on a position using a specific zoom and I want to see a marker. Before the new version of Google Maps this was working as I explained. I need the new way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this is in the format you need. The first with marker the second without

https://www.google.com/maps/place//@46.090271,6.657248,16z

https://www.google.com/maps/@46.090271,6.657248,16z

you must add the `place/` between `maps/` and `/@`

Comment: If you check my url, this is not for a static map. This is a link to open Google Maps centered on a position, with a zoom and (I wish) a marker.

Comment: The map is center by the marker postion  lat 42 lng 12  and the zoom  = 13 and size is 800x600. you can change this or create dinamic url